# Can we auto-increment a column without using trigger?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Without creating a trigger can we apply auto-increment constraint on a column in oracle sql?

Create a sequence
Example:-
CREATE SEQUENCE books_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;

will this be enough to make a column auto-increment without creating a trigger??

Comment: "will this be enough to make a column auto-increment without creating a trigger" - no, the sequence isn't related to any table. But recent versions of Oracle have identity columns which use a sequence in the background. What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Oracle database version lower then 12c, then trigger is the only way to do that.

If you're on 12c and above, you can create identity column; in background, it is still a sequence, but Oracle does *everything* for you.